# Restify: How to serve static files while not conflicting with other routes?

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a node.js app I am creating and I am using restify.  I have setup a `GET` route for some data, but I am also wanting to serve static content from my root.

GET route:

```
server.get({path : SURVEY_QUESTION_PATH, version : appVersion}, getLandingSurveyQuestions);
```

Static routes:

```
server.get(/\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: 'static',
  default: 'index.html'
}));
```

This static route is conflicting with my dynamic route: How do I serve up this static content, without conflicting with the other routes I have?  I'd hate to have to setup static routes for all of the individual files in my project.

I have tried:

1. Changing the order of the route registration
2. Tweaking the regex of the static route

Answer (score 4):

So far I have a hack: changing the regex to include the common static files that will be served up.  This seems inefficient, but works.

```
server.get(/(^\/$)|(\.(html|js|css|png|jpg)$)/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: 'static',
  default: 'index.html'
}));
```